# how to connect tomcat 7 and mysql

Tags: mysql, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee

i m quite new to j2ee.....
i just finished reading head first servlets and jsp ....

for a practice project i was thinking to build a money tracker in which i can save my expenses and see them anytime in the future....
but for this i need a database , i googled for it and found that mysql is a good database but i know nothing about how to set tomcat to talk to mysql....

and i m using eclipse kepler with tomcat 7 .......

plz  tell me what are the steps to follow to configure tomcat so that it can see mysql and i can access the database through my codes ......

i m on windows 8.

it seems like setting up things is more difficult than coding
plz plz plz help me

Answer (score 2):

These are some steps you could do:

1. Create a context.xml and save it under TOMCAT_HOME/conf.
2. Into the context.xml you have to add your DB configuration which could look like:

   `<Resource name="jdbc/test" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxActive="510" minIdle="0" maxIdle="200" maxWait="10000"
              username="test" password="test" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test"
              poolPreparedStatements="true" maxOpenPreparedStatements="510"
              validationQuery="SELECT 1" testOnBorrow="true" 
   />`
3. In the web.xml of your application refer to the above context, like:

   `<resource-ref>
     <description>DB Connection</description>
     <res-ref-name>jdbc/test</res-ref-name>
     <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
     <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
   </resource-ref>`
4. Put the JAR (e.g. mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar) containing the mysql driver into TOMCAT_HOME/lib

I hope it will help.