# I can't use JNDI in tomcat to connect MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat, jndi

I did everything in this :
[how to connect tomcat 7 and mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27089414/how-to-connect-tomcat-7-and-mysql)
But it still isn't working..... why? What have I missed?

### Enviroment

OS      : Win7
Eclipse : J2EE Mars
Tomcat  : tomcat 8.0
java    : 1.8.0_73
db name : test
username: root
password:   123

---

### controller:

```
writeDB testDB = new writeDB(tablename);
```

---

### writeDB.java

```
....
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
try{
      Context initContext = new InitialContext();
      Context envContext = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
      //-------error------- 
      dataSource = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/test");
      //-------error-------
   }catch(NamingException ex)
   {
      throw new RuntimeException(ex);   
   }
```

---

### web.xml  (in my project)

```
<!-- MySQL JNDI -->
<resource-ref>
    <description>MySQL DB</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/test</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

---

### context.xml

(in TOMCAT_HOME/conf)
(Also in workspace\Servers\Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost-config)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/eatST">
<Resource 
    name="jdbc/test"
    auth="Container" 
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActice="100" 
    maxIdle="30" 
    maxWait="10000" 
    username="root"
    password="123" 
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?
         useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF8"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
 />
 </Context>
```

---

### Logs

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [commentCtr] in context 
with path [/eatST]      threw exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource   
cannot be cast to javax.activation.DataSource
     at com.joe.db.writeDB.<init>(writeDB.java:58)
     at com.joe.servlet.CommentCtr.doPost(CommentCtr.java:38)
     at ............
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've imported (and presumable programmed to) an incorrect `DataSource`. Your exception (`java.lang.ClassCastException ... cannot be cast to javax.activation.DataSource`) is telling you that you have used`javax.activation.DataSource`, but you wanted [`javax.sql.DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html). Modify `com.joe.db.writeDB` and change

```
import javax.activation.DataSource;
```

to

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
```

Also, you don't *need* `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` (it doesn't hurt anything, but JDBC drivers register themselves now).

Comment: wow,it work! thanks a lot!!!.
But there is another exception now...         
Servlet.service() for servlet [commentCtr] in context with path [/eatST] threw exception 
java.lang.NullPointerException...

Comment: It work now~!!  I uninstalled my tomcat 8.0 and reintsall it .  Then follow this article : http://viralpatel.net/blogs/database-connection-pooling-tomcat-eclipse-db/    IDK why . I guess it's some cache problem . Poeple having same problem can  reference this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520267/localhost8080-gives-404-the-requested-resource-is-not-available